# str_to_date not working on one database while working fine on another

Tags: mysql

I have 1 live database on a server (`v5.5.58`) and one local on my computer (`v8.0.11`) that is used as a testing database.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("12:21:21", "%H:%i:%s")
```

Running this query on the server works fine while the same query locally returns date as null and a warning saying:

> Warning: #1411 Incorrect datetime value: '12:21:21' for function str_to_date

I know that `STR_TO_DATE` works on MySql version 3.23 so it should work on version 8, right?

Comment: Note that the versions you are showing are *client* versions, so not especially informative; the server version is found with `SELECT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot tnx, didn't know that. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`@@SQL_MODE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) setting differs between your servers.  Since 5.6, MySQL Server has used more strict default values for `@@SQL_MODE`.

> If the `NO_ZERO_DATE` or `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` SQL mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed. In that case, `STR_TO_DATE()` returns `NULL` and generates a warning
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

This same information appears in the documentation for previous versions.

You can often change newer servers to emulate the (usually permissive, sometimes wrong) behavior of older servers by changing the `@@SQL_MODE` to match, but do that with due discretion, since the more strict behavior is usually also more correct and helps avoid silent coercion of invalid values.

Comment: `NO_ZERO_DATE` isn't an option for me since I have multiple large databases with dates formatted as above. Is there a more elegant solution than to disable strict mode?

Comment: It seems like adding [`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates) to the set of `@@SQL_MODE` values on the new server may be the workaround you are looking for. `NO_ZERO_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` seem to be implicit in 8.0.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks!